# Latest kernel version number?

Tags: grub2, kernel

I recently upgraded from Lucid Lynx to Maverick. And then there was a kernel update which I installed. Right now when the computer boots up, on the grub boot loader I get 2 options to boot into

- Linux 2.6.35-22-generic  OR
- Linux 2.6.35-25-generic

I am booting into 2.6.35-25 assuming its newer. But, usually newer kernels are placed higher on the grub menu, but this one is below the 2.6.35-22-generic. [I don't know if that made any sense].

Anyways, which option should I choose? I usually remove older ones using synaptic and keep the latest copy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last kernel for Maverick is Linux 2.6.35-22-generic.

Are you sure the other one is 2.6.**35**-25-generic and not 2.6.**32**-25-generic (the last *Lucid* kernel)?

Comment: OMG. You are correct. Sorry about that. I feel stupid/

Comment: Nice feature of ubuntu-tweak is cleanup of those kernels :)

Answer (score 2):

In terminal, if you want only the version number you can type:

```
uname -r
```

Or if you want the complete name of the kernel you can type:

```
uname -a
```

You can use this in other commands between quotes, like for example:

```
apt-get install kernel-modules-`uname-r`
```

or `$(uname -r)`, like for example

```
apt-get install kernel-modules-$(uname -r)
```

This is also working when navigating through folders, like:

```
cd /lib/modules/'uname-r'/kernel
```

or

```
cd /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel
```